# How to close a file inside another function of the class in Python?

Tags: python, class

I got a function run(self) and inside that function I was to open a file. I then want to close that file inside another function, reset(self).

This is my class:

```
class Heater (threading.Thread):
    STATE_IDLE = "IDLE"
    STATE_RUNNING = "RUNNING"

    def __init__(self, simulate=False, time_step=config.sensor_time_wait):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.simulate = simulate
        self.time_step = time_step
        self.reset()
        if simulate:
            self.temp_sensor = TempSensorSimulate(self, 0.5, self.time_step)
        if sensor_available:
            self.temp_sensor = TempSensorReal(self.time_step)
        else:
            self.temp_sensor = TempSensorSimulate(self,
                                                  self.time_step,
                                                  self.time_step)
        self.temp_sensor.start()
        self.start()

    def reset(self):
        self.profile = None
        self.start_time = 0
        self.runtime = 0
        self.totaltime = 0
        self.target = 0

    def run(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.name = os.path.join('/storedata/store', "Date_" + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + ".txt")
        self.file = open(name, 'a')
        self.file.write(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        reset()
```

would I just put `self.file = self.run.file.close` in reset(self) to achieve this?

Comment: Because you're using classes, `self.file` can be used outside of the function anywhere inside the class, therefore just `self.file.close()`

Comment: The attribute is `self.file`, you should just call `self.file.close()`; and there is no need to reassign it back to `self.file`.

Comment: "with" gets the job done

Comment: `self.name = os.path.join(` then you're using `name` the line after. Your snippet has a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
def __init__(self, simulate=False, time_step=config.sensor_time_wait):
    self.file = None
```

now there is an attribute called `file` in your class. Set to `None`. Now

```
def __reset(self):
   if self.file:
     self.file.close()
     self.file = None
```

that should do it ! Note that `__reset` is safe to call when the file isn't opened, since the `file` attribute exists and is `None` (closing an already closed file doesn't do anything, but still, it's clearer)

Note that this design only is interesting if you're using `self.file` somewhere else. Else don't define any member just do:

```
name = os.path.join(... // your code used "self.name" for some reason
with open(name, 'a') as file:
    file.write(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

As a general rule, define class members only when necessary, and local variables anywhere else.